# Subset data within range of other values in MS excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have spreadsheet with image filenames and their corresponding lat, long, altitude info etc. I want to subset the data to get rid of overlapping images within 350m. I need to find a way to get rid of files that overlap within 350m of any other file. I can’t figure out the best way to go about this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly straightforward (well, depends on your point of view, I guess) to calculate the distance between two points whose latitude and longitude are known.  I would ignore altitude here for the sake of simplicity.

You first convert lat/long in degrees to radians with the RADIANS() function.  Then the [Haversine formula](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) figures the distance.  It is usually broken into three separate calculations, where d is the distance between the two points:

```
a = sin²(Δφ/2) + cos φ1 * cos φ2 * sin²(Δλ/2)
c = 2 * atan2( √a, √(1−a) )
d = R * c
```

Here φ is latitude, λ is longitude, and R is the radius of the Earth: 3,959 miles. Δφ and Δλ are the difference between the two latitudes and longitudes, respectively.  W longitudes and S latitudes are expressed as negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to this could be to use a mapping tool such as [this one](https://www.darrinward.com/lat-long/).

On that site, you paste a list of your latitudes and longitudes into a box, and it shows all the locations on a map.  You should be able to identify locations that are near each other by viewing the map.

To create a new data column formatted for this website, type this formula in a blank column next to your first latitude and longitude and fill down:

```
=A1&","&B1
```

This assumes your latitudes and longitudes start in A1 and B1 respectively. Change the formula to refer to the correct cells.  You can now copy the new column and paste it into the box on the linked website.

This website requires decimal lat/long, where W longitudes and S latitudes are negative numbers. If your data uses the W/S format, it can be converted easily with a formula.

I hope this works for you, this way may be much easier than calculating all the distances between your locations.  Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Use this formula in a new column, then filter on condition:

```
=if(cellofdistance <= 350; "Within Rage"; "Out of Range")
```

Where "cellofdistance" is the cell you have the distance. So erase cellofdistance and then click on on the cell with distance. Then you double click the lower down corner of the cell where you put this formula.

Comment: What is "cellofdistance" here??  There is no user column or Excel function with that name.  Interestingly, if you Google that term, the only thing that comes up is this post. :-D

Comment: @Bandersnatch that's like the cell where you have the data. Haters gonna hare i guess

Comment: if she had a cell with the distance in it (to compare to 350), she wouldn't be asking how to find it.